# Show that the expression is positive for all $x\in (0,1)$ and $1<a<b$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, polynomials

I want to show that $$f(x)=(x^{a-1}-x^b)(1-x^{a+1})(1-x^a)*(a-1)(b-a-1)(b-a) \\+(x^{a+1}-x^b)(1-x^{a-1})(1-x^a)*(a+1)(b-a+1)(b-a)\\-(x^a-x^b)(1-x^{a-1})(1-x^{a+1})*2a(b-a+1)(b-a-1)> 0$$ for all $x\in (0,1)$. Furthermore, $a$ and $b$ are integers with $1<a<b$.

Comment: What have you determined so far? A lot of the terms have obvious sign.

Comment: Any information about the question?

Comment: I was originally interested in $$g_{a, b}(x)=\frac{(x^a-x^b)a}{(1-x^a)(b-a)}.$$ I could show that $g_{a,b}(x)$ decreases in $a$, $b$, and $x$. Now I want to better understand how $g_{a,b}(x)$ behaves when $a$ increases and so I tried to examine $$f(x)=[g_{a-1,b}(x)-g_{a,b}(x)]-[g_{a,b}(x)-g_{a+1,b}(x)],$$ which is the expression above.

Comment: @CasparDavid You may use @ when you comment for some specific user. You don't use @, so I just see your comment.